# OpenGL 2D transformations without keeping aspect

Tags: opengl

I need to have a 2D layer in my OpenGL application.I have implemented it first using a typical ortho projection like this:

```
 Mat4 ortho =Glm.ortho(0,viewWidth , 0 ,viewHeight);
```

The 2d worked fine except the fact that when running in different screen sizes the 2d shapes are scaled relatively to a new aspect.That is not what I want (opposite to what usually people need). I need the 2d shapes to get stretched or squeezed according to the new screen size.

I tried not to use the ortho matrix but just an identity.This one works but in such a case I have to use numbers in range 0 -1 to manipulate the objects  in the visible frustum area.And I need to use numbers in regular (not normalized ) ranges.So it is sort of forcing me to get back to ortho projection which is problematic because of what already said.
So the question is how do I transform 2d object without  perspective staying in the world coordinates system.

**UPDATE:**

The best example is 2D layers in Adobe AfterEffects. If one changes composition dimension ,2d layers don't get scaled according to new dimensions.That is what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to know how to answer this, because to some degree your requirements are mutually exclusive. You don't want normalised coordinates, you want to use screen coordinates. But by definition, screen coordinates are defined in pixels, and pixels are usually square... So I think you need *some* form of normalised coordinates, albeit maybe uniformly scaled.

Perhaps what you want is to fix the ratio for width and height in your ortho. That would allow you to address the screen in some kind of pseudo-pixel unit, where one axis is "real" pixels, but the other can be stretched. So instead of height, pass 3/4 of the width for a 4:3 display, or 9/16ths on a 16:9, etc. This will be in units of pixels if the display is the "right" dimension, but will stretch in one dimension only if it's not.

You may need to switch which dimension is "real" pixels depending on the ratio being less or greater than your "optimal" ratio, but it's tricky to know what you're really shooting for here.

Comment: UI is usually best drawn with absolute pixel coordinates, because it (again, usually) consists of images that should be drawn pixel-perfect.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I agree, but the OP has specified he wants to do the opposite of what is usually required, so keeping *one* dimension pixel coordinates (and both in the case of the 'right' ratio) seems the best available compromise.

Comment: I created now a fixed ortho - (-1 ,1 ,-1 ,1 ) .Now I do get 2d objects stretch when the screen size changes but I have problems with 2d shapes aspect .

Comment: @MichaelIV Not sure that comment is really in reponse to my answer. I'd suggest expanding on your question. It might help to have an image or two to illustrate what is happening, and what you want to happen.